# Feature 'global using directive' is not available in JetBrainds Rider (.NET6 and C#10)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0, c#-10.0, jetbrains-rider

I am using JetBrains Rider 2023.2.3 on Mac, I am trying to build a .NET project (C#10 and .NET6), and I get the following error in this autogenerated code.

```
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::System;
global using global::System.Collections.Generic;
global using global::System.IO;
global using global::System.Linq;
global using global::System.Net.Http;
global using global::System.Threading;
global using global::System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Error:

```
0>Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): Warning NETSDK1182 : Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.
/Users/adhamenaya/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/8.0/MSBuild/6521_1/Roslyn/csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:6 /define:TRACE;DEBUG;NET;NET6_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-GB /highentropyva+ /nullable:disable /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Results.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/Users/adhamenaya/.nuget/packages/microsoft.dotnet.platformabstractions/2.1.0/lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll /reference:/Users/adhamenaya/.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.dependencymodel/2.1.0/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Features.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll  /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll /reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/ref/net6.0/WindowsBase.dll /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj/Debug/net6.0/M2.Forms.dll /refout:obj/Debug/net6.0/ref/M2.Forms.dll /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:10.0 /analyzerconfig:obj/Debug/net6.0/M2.Forms.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig /analyzerconfig:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/analyzers/build/config/analysislevel_6_default.editorconfig /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/analyzers/cs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/analyzers/cs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/analyzers/cs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/../analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/../analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.CodeFixes.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.6/analyzers/dotnet/roslyn4.0/cs/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/targets/../source-generators/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Internal.SourceGenerator.Transport.dll /analyzer:/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.106/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/targets/../source-generators/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll Program.cs obj/Debug/net6.0/M2.Forms.GlobalUsings.g.cs "obj/Debug/net6.0/.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj/Debug/net6.0/M2.Forms.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
0>CSC: Error CS1617 : Invalid option '10.0' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?' to list supported values.
0>------- Finished building project: M2.Forms. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 1
```

Could you please advise what is the problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: Does it only happen when using Rider or within VS as well? Furthermore, does it only happen within your `M2.Forms` project or in other projects/solution as well?